# Docker, Debezium not streaming data from mssql to elasticsearch

Tags: sql-server, docker, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, debezium

I followed this examples to stream data from mysql to elasticsearch
https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/tree/master/unwrap-smt#elasticsearch-sink
The example itself works great on my local machine.

But in my case I want to stream data from mssql (which is on another server, not docker) to elasticsearch.

So in the "docker-compose-es.yaml" file i removed "mysql" part and removed the mysql links.
And created my own connectors/sink for elastic and mssql:

```
{
    "name": "Test-connector", 
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector", 
        "database.hostname": "192.168.1.234", 
        "database.port": "1433", 
        "database.user": "user", 
        "database.password": "pass", 
        "database.dbname": "Test", 
        "database.server.name": "MyServer",
        "table.include.list": "dbo.TEST_A",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092", 
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.testA"
    }
}
```

```
{
    "name": "elastic-sink-test",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "TEST_A",
        "connection.url": "http://localhost:9200/",
        "transforms": "unwrap,key",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope",    
        "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",    
        "transforms.key.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
        "transforms.key.field": "SQ",                                                 
        "key.ignore": "false",                                                        
        "type.name": "TEST_A",
        "behavior.on.null.values": "delete"                                                     
    }
}
```

When adding these the kafka connect I/O is working hard and has over 40GB input see image below:

[image]

In the kafka logs it looks like its going through all the tables. Here is one of the table logs:

```
2021-06-17 10:20:10,414 - INFO [data-plane-kafka-request-handler-5:Logging@66] - [Partition MyServer.dbo.TemplateGroup-0 broker=1] Log loaded for partition MyServer.dbo.TemplateGroup-0 with initial high watermark 0
2021-06-17 10:20:10,509 - INFO [data-plane-kafka-request-handler-3:Logging@66] - Creating topic MyServer.dbo.TemplateMeter with configuration {} and initial partition assignment Map(0 -> ArrayBuffer(1))
2021-06-17 10:20:10,516 - INFO [data-plane-kafka-request-handler-3:Logging@66] - [KafkaApi-1] Auto creation of topic MyServer.dbo.TemplateMeter with 1 partitions and replication factor 1 is successful
2021-06-17 10:20:10,526 - INFO [data-plane-kafka-request-handler-7:Logging@66] - [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 1] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(MyServer.dbo.TemplateMeter-0)
2021-06-17 10:20:10,528 - INFO [data-plane-kafka-request-handler-7:Logging@66] - [Log partition=MyServer.dbo.TemplateMeter-0, dir=/kafka/data/1] Loading producer state till offset 0 with message format version 2
```

The database is only 2GB. I'm not sure why it has so high input.

No test_a index was created in elasticsearch when running this command:
`curl http://localhost:9200/_aliases?pretty=true`

Does anyone know how I troubleshoot from here or point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how I troubleshoot from here

`docker compose logs`?

Modify the log4j.properties of Kafka Connect and/or Elasitcsearch processes to get more logs?

Use a regular Kafka consumer to see if data is actually read into the `TEST_A` topic?

> in the "docker-compose-es.yaml" ....

If Debezium is running in a container, then Elasticsearch is not available at localhost:9200

Change that value to `http://elastic:9200`, [like shown in the `es-sink.json`](https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/blob/master/unwrap-smt/es-sink.json#L7)

Comment: Great! Changed the url to http://elastic:9200 and elasticsearch created a index test_a. But it didn't fill the index with documents. 

Running this command curl "http://localhost:9092/topics" returns no topics is that correct or should I create a topic?

Comment: Kafka on port 9092 is not an HTTP server, so I dont understand your question.

Comment: By default, the source connector should be creating a topic, but you're welcome to create one before creating the connectors, sure. You wouldn't use curl to do that or check it, however

Comment: I managed to list the topics by doing:
docker exec -it unwrap-smt_kafka_1 bash

./bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper zookeeper:2181

I tried to check if the topics contained any messages with:
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test_a --from-beginning

But getting this error:
```Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)```
Any idea, how I fix the broker?

Comment: I figured it out it should be ```./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --topic test_a --from-beginning```

From there I saw a lot of topics from all tables in my test database even though i had
```"table.include.list": "dbo.TEST_A"``` I wonder why?

Apart from that it seems like "elastic-sink-test" created "test_a" topic while "Test-connector" created "MyServer.dbo.TEST_A" so I changed the elastic connectors topic to "MyServer.dbo.TEST_A" and it updated my ES database!